# Sent transaction to wETH for a swap - funds gone now

Tags: web3js

I have sent a transaction to the weth contract using web3. I called the deposit method like I always did but this time I got a bunch of pending transactions that werent processed.

I sent 0 eth to my own wallet with the nonce values of the pending transactions and they went through (or more like got dropped from etherscan). But now I dont have any funds.

I sent like 20 transactions each trying to swap 1 ETH and they all got stuck with a web3 error msg

nonce value too low.

Now everything is cleared but funds not showing up as wETH.

Answer (score 0):

need your address for details.

Are your ETH gone?

Maybe gas price too low and this transaction pending or some similar.